# How can I get this type of navigation transition?

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, transition

I want a transition like this. 
[Custom Transition](https://youtu.be/48riuVtfhbM)

Comment: You need to share more information. Is it a transition between two UIViewControllers or just panning in a view? Is it activated from a button push or gesture or both? How do you want to navigate back? Do you also need the bottom bar to disappear?

Answer (score 0):

You can customize your transition using **CATransition**

```
CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
animation.delegate = self;
animation.duration = 0.25f;
animation.timingFunction = UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut;
animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
animation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
animation.type = kCATransitionPush;
animation.subtype = kCATransitionFromTop;
[YourView.view.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"animation"];
[self.view addSubview:bView];
```

Comment: I need the exact output like the video's animation.

Comment: You can do this using CATransition. Try it first